# Why is this exception thrown in java mail?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

I am running an executor service to send emails. I am using apache tomcat 9. I am getting this exception in the process of sending emails. It says **the web application has been stopped already** . But I find the server running properly.

```
  06-Jun-2017 15:15:16.063 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal acces
s: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/javamail.providers]. The following stack trace is throw
n for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/javamail
.providers]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the ille
gal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:923)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1139)
        at javax.mail.Session$5.run(Session.java:1231)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.mail.Session.getResources(Session.java:1225)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadAllResources(Session.java:1137)
        at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:902)
        at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:219)
        at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:241)
        at com.abc.wpp.mail.SendMediaEmail.sendMediaEmail(SendMediaEmail.java:34)
        at com.abc.wpp.mail.EmailService$1.run(EmailService.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the exception causing line in java:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                password);
                    }
                });
```

What do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: Looks like you need a file named `javamail.providers` on your classpath

Comment: I think we need to know about your configuration.  What server are you using?  What JavaMail jar file(s) are you using?  JavaMail will try to load that optional configuration file in case you've provided your own JavaMail provider.  Most people don't.  Failure to find that file is not an error.  If your server is throwing IllegalStateException, something is broken.

Comment: It seems that the code works sporadically. The remote mail server must not be giving a session to me all the times?

Comment: You need to start, stop, and wait for termination of your thread poll in a servlet context listener.  By doing so your web app will not be allowed to shutdown until your thread pool has become idle.  Your tasks need to be responsive to interruption.